# How to create translucent (with content behind it) UITabBar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have subclassed UITabBar and overriden drawRect: method to make it transparent (and make it look like I need to). Problem I am having is that the view added to UITabBarController does not cover whole screen but ends 49 pixels above bottom, so even tho I have transparent tabbar, I can't see thing behind it.

Is there proper way how I can set size of UIView inside UITabBarController to cover entire screen?

P.S.:I know it is not good idea to show content behind tabbar. I do not want to show any content there, just art, that is specific to each View and needs to be visible through tabbar.

Comment: Have you solved that issue? What option works for you?

Comment: I ended up doing my own tab bar controller, it was easier than I thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have content behind the `UITabBar`, I see two options:

- Don't use `UITabBarController` – This will definitely work, because you can position the views as you want and it is not *so* difficult to implement it.
- **Try** turning off `clipsToBounds` on the view and place some view out of his bounds.

  ```
  // UIViewController contained in UITabBarController:
  self.view.clipsToBounds = NO;
  UIView *viewBehindTabBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
  viewBehindTabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height,
                                      self.view.bounds.size.width, 49);
  // autoresizing mask, background color, ...
  [self.view addSubview:viewBehindTabBar];
  ```

Comment: I tried setting clipsToBounds to false, but I had troubles resizing the View to whole screen. I guess you are right about ditching UITabBarController, it shouldn't be hard to make do without it

Comment: You can fake the effect with tabBarController.tabBar.alpha = 0.8; Obvious downside is the tabbaritems become translucent too. Better to just roll your own for this instance.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply create a category of UITabBar or UITabBarController
and set It's `Alpha`.

Something Like :-

```
@implementation UITabBarController (Translucent)
- (void)createImage
{
     [self.tabBar setAlpha:0.1];
}
@end
```

You can set Alpha even in Drawrect .

Comment: this will just make tabbar transparent (which I already have) and allows you to see what is behind UITabBarController's view (that would be UIWindow). It will not make the content UIView reach bottom of the screen which is what I need